# Qt Creator could not determine debugger type - Android Debugger

Tags: android, c++, qt, debugging

I am trying to configure Qt Creator 4.11.0 to debug an Android application. after deploying it to an android device. I can successfully build the application, but I cannot debug it, as Qt Creator apparently cannot determine the debugger type of the auto-detected Android Debugger for Android Clang.

[image: The error in question]

I tried to switch to a newer version of Qt creator (9.0.2) and re-install Qt as a whole, to no avail.
What could be the cause of this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up solving this by upgrading to Qt Creator 9.0.2 and reinstalling the NDK (multiple different versions). This highlighted a new problem, which somehow did not show before: the `gdb` version inside the NDK could not run because I did not have `libncurses5` installed. After installing it, the debugger was finally recognized.
So, in short, the fix was

```
apt install libncurses5
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to run the gdb manually in a terminal? (Permission rights)
I see it's in home, so you shouldn't have any permission issues, but you never know until you check/try.

Did you tried another version of gdb (not 20) or even another QT-Creator version?

Or maybe you need to install necessary devices yet like here:
https://developernote.com/2021/12/configuring-android-ndk-version-in-qt-creator/
(Scroll also down, there is a solution, with replacing some json-content).

Cheers

Comment: Hi Mr. Oz, thanks for your time. With regards to your questions: gdb runs fine in the console, the problem persists even with the next version of NDK gdb (21) and with Qt Creator 9.0.2, and the .json config files mentioned in the link don't seem to exist on Ubuntu.